# Saving Android ImageView Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, save

So I have this weird Issue. 9/10 times it will work perfectly fine, but that 10% will not work at all.

I am trying to simply have an ImageView that I can zoom and pan. that works great- then I try to save the imageView to the phone itself. This is where MOST of the time it will work, but then sometimes it will save the image as a black screen...and not what's actually displayed on the ImageView.

Here is my code for saving the ImageView:

```
protected void saveZoomedImage(){

    //create ImageView Bitmap
    RelativeLayout tableContent;
    tableContent=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.imgHolder);
    tableContent.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(tableContent.getLayoutParams().width, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(tableContent.getLayoutParams().height,MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
    tableContent.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    final Bitmap screenshot = Bitmap.createBitmap(tableContent.getDrawingCache());
    tableContent.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

    //save file
    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory () + "/thedir");
    if(!folder.exists()){
        folder.mkdir();
    }
    String exsistingFileName=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/thedir";
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {           
        fos = new FileOutputStream(exsistingFileName + "/image.jpg");
        screenshot.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

it saves the file fine, but it just seems like it doesn't capture the image for some reason on a small %age of times.

Comment: You call `tableContent.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);` twice. Did you mean False the second time?

Comment: ah yes lol- Think that could have caused the issue though?

Comment: I don't know. it's possible, i think. It's the only thing that stood out to me. If you have an error message that comes with the 10th time, it might help further if you edited your post to include it.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately no crash or error message when it saves a black space-
I'll give this change a try.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that your app has the storage permission enabled:

Go to Device Settings>Device>Applications>Application Manager>"your app">Permissions>Enable Storage permission!

Permissions in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

So, if you want to create your own directory in your File Storage you can use somethibng like:

```
String myDate = getCurrentDateAndTime();
FileOutputStream outStream = null;
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/YourFolderName");
dir.mkdirs();
String fileName = "YourFileName_"+myDate+".jpg";
File outFile = new File(dir, fileName);
outStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
outStream.flush();
outStream.close();
//to refresh the gallery
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

}

Helper function:

```
private String getCurrentDateAndTime() {
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss");
String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
return formattedDate;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Could you describe your answer a bit more

Comment: Edited my answer! Good luck!

Comment: Dude, I gave you up vote before commenting. We are trying to help each other. That's all

Comment: I just said that I have edited the answer with more explanation! Nothing else! I also voted! Cool

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public static String saveImageInExternalCacheDir(Context context, Bitmap bitmap, String myfileName) {
    String fileName = myfileName.replace(' ', '_') + getCurrentDate().toString().replace(' ', '_').replace(":", "_");
    String filePath = (context.getExternalCacheDir()).toString() + "/" + fileName + ".jpg";
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath));
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return filePath;
}
```